# Chrome Debugger hovering over variable doesn't pop up variable details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

[image: Chrome debugger]

I have the latest chrome version (Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)).  However, I am unable to view variable details when hovering over the variable in debugger mode.  How can I fix this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334180/bug-on-hover-in-chrome-debugger-v79-0-3945-79/59430390#59430390

Comment: It seems that now they fixed the bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same problem with the same version of Chrome. While waiting for a Chrome update, I recommend switching to Chromium.
https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/

Or you can downgrade Chrome.
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7125792

Comment: Thanks @koba! I was able to make it work with this version: https://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/download

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the Variable to watch? If yes then what is the value?