# Bug on hover in chrome debugger? (v79.0.3945.79)

Tags: react-native, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging a React Native 0.61.5 app with Chrome and usually when code stop running on a breakpoint and I hover a property, I can see all the details of it in a popup window. But for two days now I can't get back this functionality. I restarted computer, cleaned Chrome and Metro bundler, tried with virtual or real device but it's still not working. Did I deactivated something accidentally ?

Comment: It's issue in recent chrome update. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16855096?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with last Google Chrome update I was not able to resolve this issue. The issue comes from the Chromium version of Google Chrome.

You need the version 81 of Chromium who fixes the bug.

I downloaded the last Chromium browser with Chromium 81 and it's working for me https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/fr/

Answer (score 2):

Update: 
The issue seems to be resolved with the new Chrome update 79.0.3945.117.

Yes, with Chrome 79 this functionality was broken. This is the thread where people are reporting this bug:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22882968?hl=en

(and also in the link from the comment to this question)

And this is a thread where Chrome developers are tracking this issue and trying to fix it:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033022

In Chrome Canary (81) this feature is working, and it's reportedly working in the Chrome Dev version (80). Other alternatives are Firefox (also people say that it's working in Opera and other browsers) and debugging via VSCode.

It seems they aren't going to fix it until the version 80, which isn't expected to be released until February (from what people say in that thread: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22882968?hl=en).

Also there was this change: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/%2B/1835357 
which made variables appear on hover only inside the innermost scope. Update: this feature (to evaluate outside the innermost scope) will probably be restored: 
(from https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033022)

"This undoes
http://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1835357,
which limited the eager popover evaluation to the innermost scope, which
is the only scope for which we can produce reliable results right now.
For the outer scopes, it might still produce the right results, but we
can't guarantee that. But the feature is still very useful and so we are
restoring the behavior here, and will follow up with a proper fix and UX
later".